# Learning French to read the philosophical texts

Tags: ressources, philosophie

I'm a beginner in French and I want to learn it only in order to read the contemporary philosophical articles and books in French. As far as possible, I'm not interested in getting acquaintance with the words and phrases used in the greetings, the travels and so on. Is there any app or book which is suitable for this purpose?

Comment: My university offered a reading course, focused heavily on grammar and translation, to graduate students who needed to know certain languages. I’m not sure how successful these are though. French may be relatively easier if you know English, since there are a lot of cognates.

Comment: A web search for `reading textbooks french grad students` gives a lot of suggestions. Someone else may be able to offer more specific suggestions.

Comment: There are two skills necessary to read technical literature in French. (1) A rudimentary grasp of French grammar and common words. (2) The technical vocabulary necessary for the field. Any beginning French course will teach you the first; the second is field-specific. For technical vocabulary, a clever trick is to look up the Wikipedia article of the term you want to translate. In the sidebar, there's a link to the corresponding Wikipedia article in several languages, and the link to *anglais* or *French* will give you the technical translation.